# script to disallow mounting of certain idVendor

Tags: bash, kernel, udev, unmount

I'm trying to write a script to disallow mounting of certain usb thumb drive's brand like silicon-power my thought was to use `tail -f /var/log/messages` and `grep` it to `idVendor` and blocking it upon detection can sombody help me on this please? im using centos 7 btw.

Comment: Welcome! We're not a script writing service, but can help with specifics.. We just need more info from you.. What have you got so far? Where are you getting stuck exactly?

Comment: thank you, i wrote my code below can you pls help me figure that out?

Answer (score 1):

Write an udev rule that matches devices by their `idVendor` attribute (`ATTR{idVendor}`) and writes `0` to the `authorized` and/or `1` to `remove` attributes, causing Linux to eject the device.

<sup>(Really, you even tagged your question [udev](/questions/tagged/udev)...)</sup>

Comment: i did the udev thing but i couldnt do it right i guess, here is what i wrote: `SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="[VENDOR ID]", ATTR{idProduct}=="[PRODUCT ID]",ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1" `